# How to add the custom widget ICON in elementor

Tags: php, css, wordpress, elementor

I am developing a custom widget for the **Elementor** editor in Wordpress.

I want to set the custom widget ICON, the Elementor provides the get_icon function in that we have to return the class which has :before pseudo-element and it renders in the browser.

Is there any way to use png or any other formats to update the ICON to the Elementor widget.

Even I tried using the class with content as empty and background-image. It's not working.

Document to create a custom widget in the Elementor:
https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do it by default options, one way you can do is add class like `mywidget-icon-1` and use css to set background image.  But one thing is make sure you are overding the css using `! important` in property or more specific selector

Answer (score 1):

The following can be solutions.

Added a class and apply the background image for the class. below is the css snippets.

```
.elementor-element .icon .class-name:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(logo-name.png);
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

But the issue with this is, it will not support the Light and Drak background in the Elementor.

Instead, u can create a font from the SVG file and create an own font-family for that using @font-face.

**Defining font-family and using it**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'aweber-font';
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'aweber-font' !important;
}
.logo:before {
   content: 'value';
}
```